# Nested subqueries in java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am unable to write code for nested subquery in java spark. I looked through the documentation, but it did not help me, or I did not find the source of knowledge.
For example on SQL:

```
select o.*
,(select max(i.num_column) from some_table i where i.id = o.id and i.code<>i.prev_code) max_val
from some_table o
```

I write code for java:

```
Dataset<Row> newDataSet = someDataset.as("o")
        .withColumn(
                "MAX_VAL",
                lit(someDataset.select(max("num_column "))
                        .where(col("id").equalTo(col("o.id")))
                .first().get(0))
        );
```

But I am getting an error

> "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [max(num_column)];;"

I need code without using `spark.sql("some big sql query")`.

I would be grateful for any help)
(Java 8, Spark 3)

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-write it as a join:

```java
Dataset<Row> someDataset = spark.sql(
    "select array(named_struct('id', 'a', 'num_column', 1, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b'), "+
    "named_struct('id', 'a', 'num_column', 2, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b')"+
    ",named_struct('id', 'c', 'num_column', 3, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b')) nested_ar")
    .selectExpr("explode(nested_ar) o").selectExpr("o.*");
Dataset<Row> maxDataset = someDataset.where(
    col("code").notEqual(col("prev_code"))).
    groupBy("id").max("num_column")
    .select(col("id").as("mid"), col("max(num_column)").as("MAX_VAL"));

Dataset<Row> newDataSet = someDataset.as("o")
    .join(maxDataset, someDataset.col("id").equalTo(maxDataset.col("mid")))
    .drop("mid");

newDataSet.show();
```

yielding:

```
+---+----------+----+---------+-------+
| id|num_column|code|prev_code|MAX_VAL|
+---+----------+----+---------+-------+
|  c|         3|   a|        b|      3|
|  a|         2|   a|        b|      2|
|  a|         1|   a|        b|      2|
+---+----------+----+---------+-------+
```

If you are ok with a bit of sql, this is - IMO - far more readable:

```java
Dataset<Row> someDataset = spark.sql(
    "select array(named_struct('id', 'a', 'num_column', 1, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b'), "+
            "named_struct('id', 'a', 'num_column', 2, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b')"+
            ",named_struct('id', 'c', 'num_column', 3, 'code', 'a', 'prev_code', 'b')) nested_ar")
    .selectExpr("explode(nested_ar) o").selectExpr("o.*");
someDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("i");

Dataset<Row> newDataSet = someDataset.as("o").withColumn("MAX_VAL",
    expr("(select max(i.num_column) from i where i.id == o.id and i.code <> i.prev_code)")
    );
```

due to the <> check you'll need 3.4.0 at least (Databricks 12.2 LTS also supports this) and the brackets around the sub query are not optional.  This approach allows you to use in place and let Spark re-write it into joins.